# pimcore: How to enable zend's automatic routing

Tags: zend-framework, routes, pimcore

I read through the Zend Controller doco and it says that it can do routing as follows:

example.com/controller/action

But in Pimcore this seems to be disabled. I have to define static routes.
I don't mind defining the routes, but the thing is my regular expressions aren't very good.

Can someone explain to me if it is possible to enable the normal zend controller style routing as above and stop having to make use of the pimcore's built in static routes?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you just create a document, go to settings and add your controller and action and then use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to enable the normal zend controller style routing, without breaking pimcore. There are 2 possibilities:

1. use `example.org/?controller=controllername&action=actionname` for direct access to a controller-action (as described in the [Pimcore Documentation - Magic Parameters](https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/Magic+Parameters))
2. use the built in [static routes](https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=655530). For example:

   pattern: |/news/list|, controller: news, action: list

Answer (score 0):

have a look at pimcore plugins for that. /pugin/name/controller/action/ ...